# Creating a branch in a SVN repo without a trunk

Tags: svn

Is it possible to create a branches folder in a SVN repo without a trunk?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8546106/creating-a-branch-with-tortoisesvn-without-trunk-structure

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange stuff however you like.  The trunk/branches/whatever is just a common setup, so people will know where to look for stuff.  But you can call the folders whatever you want, or put them anywhere you want, or not have them at all.

The only catch is, if your branches folder is in the place where your other files are, checking out the repo will also download all the branches.  You can set the include depth to "exclude" to avoid that, but it takes some fiddling in the repo browser.  That's all part of the reason "trunk" gets its own directory.